# Absolutely position an image bottom left page - it just won't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image stick to just above the footer on the bottom left hand side of the main content, under a left nav, but what with all the floats etc, I simply cannot make it stay where I want it. [Here's a link:](https://www.inside-guides.co.uk/feedback.asp?). I've tried margins, positioning on left nav elements - you name it.

I'd love a fresh pair of eyes to have a look for me, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS so we can see :)
Also, which image do you want to stick to which part of the page?

Comment: @sue: The page you link to just gets redirected to `Default.asp` instead of displaying `feedback.asp`. Please provide a new working link or the code. :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for the replies, here's a different page http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/about-us.html.  Any chance you could check the source in chrome inspector or IE dev tools instead of posting lengthy css/html?  Thanks so much...

Comment: I like the colors of the footer.

Comment: The image is at the bottom left hand corner (the signpost)... Any ideas anyone?  I'm sure someone knows :)

Comment: @Developer Art - thanks vm, I like them too :)

Comment: Do you need the css/html?  I can post of course, but it'll be a lot quicker to quickly check in Chrome Inspector or IE Dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

Solved for anyone else who wants to know - I didn't add the correct margin under the #leftnav.