# Absolutely position an image - bottom left of page

Tags: html, css

Again..

I'm trying to make an image stick to just above the footer on the bottom left hand side of the main content, under a left nav, but there needs to be a gap between the bottom of the left nav and the signpost which there currently isn't. [Here's a link:](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/about-us.html)

Grateful for any advice.  Oh and if you could perhaps check in Chrome Inspector as opposed to posting all the code, it would save me time and you, tedium...

Comment: margin: 10px; will place 10px gap around the signpost. Or you could use margin-bottom: 10px on the left-nav

Comment: Thanks Adam for your reply, but I've tried that of course... Sorry i forgot to mention - feel's like I've tried everything!  Any other ideas?  Cheers...

Comment: I cant see why that wouldn't work. What were the results of that.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267699/absolutely-position-an-image-bottom-left-page-it-just-wont-work

Answer (score 0):

If you change the margin-bottom of #left-nav to 110px, then you will have that space. Your absolutely positioned element will not be pushed down by the left nav's margin because it its no longer positioned "relatively", if that makes any sense. The margin of your left nav is pushing up against the bottom of your #maincontent area when you bump it up to 110px.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought (mega dumb not to do it) - and yep makes perfect sense.  I tried the extra margin on the #leftnav and didn't seem to work - but I'll have another go @ 110px.  Thanks very much mmurch...

Answer (score 0):

```
#signpost {
padding-top:10px;
}
```